# Sending and Receiving Soap request in java soap webservice

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I have created a simple soap web-service for adding two number. I have published it and created client and tested. It's all working fine.

I want to send soap request in XML format means with soap header, soap envelop and soap body part. My doubt is how can I send the request in soap format. Whether I need to attach a soap XML format file or what?

Also, I want to accept soap format request in my web-service code? How do I do that ?